# How do you make explode particles be exempt from forces

Tags: particles

[image]

I am trying to make the particles come together again but the forces i added for the other particles are interfering with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In particle system, there is the Effector collection field that you can use to limit forces. Only forces that's located in the collection will be taken into account.

[image]